# Change Minecraft Server Name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm setting up a minecraft server for just myself and friends. I'm using the official server (on windows) from minecraft.net
I got it all up and working but I'm curious how to change the Server Name. It looks like before 1.8.1 you could just add `server-name=my server` to the `server.properties` file, but now that doesn't seem to work. Googling didn't seem to return any helpful results, is it possible to change the server name and not just the MoTD?

[image]

Comment: I believe thats set by the user that connects. You can change the MOTD, but not the server name.

Comment: Oh... Well, that's lame...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way of changing that. Users pick what they want that to say when they add it from the "add server" menu.

The MOTD ("Leg Day" in your example) is what you can change for everyone. You can find it in the server.properties file.

Comment: That, and the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but that is only changeable by the user. The more gray text can be edited in the server.properties file, but not the area you have in the red box.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to go to `server.properties` and change `level-name:(serverName)`.

Comment: confirmed to be incorrect on the minecraft wikia. level-name changes the folder name, not the server, itself.